# What is wrong with this apache virtualhost directive?

Tags: apache

I'm getting 403 forbidden errors with this virtualhost directory in apache 2.2. Can anyone help, please?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.xyz.com
  ServerAlias xyz.com
  DocumentRoot "/home/bruce/projects/links/www"

  <Directory />
    AllowOverride None
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.jsp index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks!

EDIT error in log is

```
(13)Permission denied: access to / denied
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with your virtualhost its wrong with your folder. you need to set 755 to the folder links and www.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not wrong you have indicated the root directory of you file system in `< Directory>`
It should be:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.xyz.com
ServerAlias xyz.com
DocumentRoot "/home/bruce/projects/links/www"

<Directory /home/bruce/projects/links/www>
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ended up being something simpler than that. Actual permissions on the directories.. Gah!

Answer (score 0):

Gah. It ended up being that I was indeed forbidden from accessing that page. I am using a new virtual server provider, and they have set up my /home account as readable only by me. As a result, the user running apache was unable to view the files. I've changed the permissions on my home directory to be more lenient and now everything works as expected.